# Accidentally deleted git ignored file in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, git, github-actions, gitignore

I accidentally deleted a file that was in `.gitignore`, let's call the file `abc`. Since the file was an important asset and was located in `pubspec.yaml` under the "asset" entry, every time the workflow starts it fails when it runs "flutter analyze". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is git-ignored, git does not track it (unless it was forcibly added, but then it's not really ignored even though it appears in the `.gitignore` file). Unless you have some other filesystem backup, I fear you're out of luck.